# Using external test data in protractor test

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am trying to reference test data using a JSON but it appears as undefined. I am trying to use a Page Object Model and reference external test data. When referencing the values in my test data and passing into a function they are appearing as `undefined`

I have a simple JSON like:

```
[{
        "userNameValue": "mrUserUser",
        "passwordValue": "i_am_correct"
}]
```

My tests then look like:

```
 'use strict';
var testData = require('./testData/testData.json');
var AngularPage = require('./pages/logon.page.js');

describe('travel portal logon page', function () {
var logonPage;

beforeEach(function () {
logonPage = new AngularPage();
});
it('should fail to logon', function() {
logonPage.loginToSite(testData.userNameValue, testData.passwordValue);
expect(logonPage.errorMessageText).toEqual('Invalid Login');
});
});
```

Both `testData.userNameValue` and `testData.passwordValue` are being written as `undefined`. I have also tried referencing using the other format of `testData['userNameValue']`.

Am I missing something?

Please help, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have exported your `testData.json` file as required using `module.exports` function. Also your test data is not an object in the first place, its an array. In order for your test script to work, change the test data into an object. Here's how -

```
var testData = {
    "userNameValue": "mrUserUser",
    "passwordValue": "i_am_correct"
};
```

If you want to keep the testData the way it is now(an array), then change the way you access the data in your test steps. Here's how -

```
logonPage.loginToSite(testData[0].userNameValue, testData[0].passwordValue);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, yes I would like to continue to use Json Arrays.  Using the reference you suggested worked!

Comment: @fatmanmclone90 check http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers if it solved your problem. Thanks